# wso2am - disable oauth consent form

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Using wso2am 2.1.0 - is it possible to disable / skip the OAuth auhtorization approval (the screen where user confirms using API by specific application and scope) ? I am almost sure I've seen such an option (parameter), but I cannot recall where..

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found it by myself, in the identity.xml there are options:

`OpenIDSkipUserConsent`
and
 `SkipUserConsent`

Comment: For OAuth / OIDC you need to change SkipUserConsent. other option you have mentioned OpenIDSkipUserConsent is for openId